# Find two distinct permutations in $S(4)$ which commute, are not disjoint and neither is the identity and they are not inverses of each other.

Tags: group-theory

Find two distinct permutations in $S(4)$ which commute, are not disjoint and neither is the identity and they are not inverses of each other.

I haven't been able to figure out which permutations will satisfy these policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look for a subgroup of $S_4$ having four elements.

Comment: So $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @UsernameUnknown This one is good, too.

Comment: How do I show that this satisfy these properties?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown They are elements in a cyclic subgroup of $S_4$, so they commute with each other.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Cayley's theorem tells us that, for any group $G$ such that $|G| = n$, then $G \leq S_n$.  Certainly, there are abelian groups of order $4$.